# how to validate php site with html5 validator

Tags: php, html, validation

i have a web application in php with html5, want to validate in html5, i don't know how to validate with html5. Advice me a solution fore these. Also i want to add html5 validation code to my application

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is publicly available, you can enter your URL into the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). The W3 validator will reveal errors and warnings in your markup.

If your site is not yet public, you can click the "Validate by Direct Input" tab and paste your markup for validation.

Additionally, there are several other tools that provide markup services directly in your browser, such as the validator included with the [Web Developer Toolbar.](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)

Comment: i had lots of inner pages which can be seen only after log in to site. How can i test these pages with these validation servise

Comment: You can use the direct input method (which may be tedious with lots of pages) or use one of the browser tools such as the Web Developer Toolbar.